# I want to give communication between two html's in gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

`I want to add a widget from one html to another html using RootPanel onlyin onemodule otherwise i need to maintain state between two html`

> this is entry point in one html

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
                Button button=new Button("click me");
                button.addClickHandler((ClickHandler) this);
                RootPanel rootPanel=RootPanel.get("id_html1");
                rootPanel.add(button);
            }
```

this is for another html i want to add this widget here using RootPane

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
 String url="http://localhost:9090/HelloWorld/"+"HelloWorld2.html";
                Window.open(url, "_blank", "");
                Button button=new Button("finish it!");
                //button.addClickHandler((ClickHandler) this);
                RootPanel rootPanel=RootPanel.get("id_html2");
                rootPanel.add(button);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to do. It's not more clear that the the post you've put "How to maintain state between two modules in gwt". Try to be be clear and perhaps you will get some answer and help....

Comment: I suggest that you start with a tutorial on GWT. In GWT you do not "communicate between two HTMLs". In GWT you can build as complex app as you want, but the entire app resides in a single HTML page.